# [Vertica][Support] (50310) Unrecognized ICU conversion error

Tags: sql, ssis, odbc, ssis-2012, vertica

I get following error when i try to load a field from vertica DB which has data type "Long Varchar" using SSIS.

> [Extract Data from Vertica "Fact_Service_Case_View" [2]] Error: Open
>   Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: 'HY000'. Native
>   Error Code: 50310. [Vertica][Support] (50310) Unrecognized ICU
>   conversion error.

how do i handle this error

Comment: The best I can find: https://forum.vertica.com/discussion/220737/unrecognized-icu-conversion-error-using-pyodbc it may be that you are using an outdated version of your driver